# Spark scala : select column name from other dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

There are two json and first json has more column and always it is super set.

```
val df1 = spark.read.json(sqoopJson)
val df2 = spark.read.json(kafkaJson)
```

**Except Operation :**

I like to apply except operation on both df1 and df2, But df1 has 10 column and df2 has only 8 columns.
In case manually if i drop 2 column from df1 then except will work. But I have 50+ tables/json  and need to do EXCEPT for all 50 set of tables/json.

**Question :**

How to select only columns available in DF2 ( 8) columns from DF1 and create new df3? So df3 will have data from df1 with limited column and it will match with df2 columns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**For the Question:** *How to select only columns available in DF2 ( 8) columns from DF1 and create new df3?*

```
//Get the 8 column names from df2 
val columns = df2.schema.fieldNames.map(col(_))

//select only the columns from df2 
val df3 = df1.select(columns :_*)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: its working as expected, Thanks lot for your response